# Angular - Submenu routes back to home page

Tags: html, angular, adminlte

I have this sub-menu in Angular-12 and AdminLTE3 theme:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">
    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
    <p>
      School Admin
      <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
    </p>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/access']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>User Access Overview</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/users']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>Users</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/role']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>Role</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

This works well in plain HTML, but behaves abnormally in Angular.

When user clicks on the main menu (School Admin), it suppose to dropdown as treeview and display the sub-menus:

**School Admin**

- User Access Overview
- Users
- Role

But instead of this, it goes to the home page.

Could it be bacause of the href="#" ?

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link" (click)="viewSubMenu=!viewSubMenu">
    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
    <p>
      School Admin
      <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
    </p>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-treeview" *ngIf="viewSubMenu">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/access']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>User Access Overview</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/users']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>Users</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/role']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>Role</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Does it mean I will declare viewSubMenu in the component before getting to the HTML

Comment: <a href="#" class="nav-link" (click)="viewSubMenu=!viewSubMenu">   still takes me to the home page. And when I remove   href="#"  it remains on the same spot, but the submenu did not open

Comment: if its not working that way then declare viewSubMenu:boolean = false in component and try , i am using the above code for my sidemenu in my projects but not sure why its not working in ur case , try this and let me know if i works

Comment: (click)="openNav()"    openNav():void{ viewSubMenu = true} ,  try this too

Comment: Do I still need to put href="#"